# Google Analytics Limits and Quotas on API Requests (Reporting APIs request errors)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

GA [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors):

> If your request to the Reporting API fails and you get a response code 500 or 503, you can resubmit it. Google Analytics allows:
>
> - 10 failed requests per project per profile per hour
> - 50 failed requests per project per profile per day

> If the number of your failed requests exceeds these quotas, you'll get the following error...

How does GA count these failed requests and set limits? For example, you get a response code 500 at 15:50. So at 15:50 you have 1 error per hour and 1 error per day (the same). The error counter per hour in GA is reset to zero at 16:00 or 16:50?
In the documentation (another section) it is written that

> Daily quotas are refreshed at midnight Pacific Standard Time

Does this also apply to failed requests (day's counter)?
How long the profile restriction lasts after exceeding the limits (attempt to make a request to GA after 10 failed requests)

Answer (score 1):

For the failed requests quota, GA counts these failed requests by a continuous running window. In your example, the error counter per hour in GA is reset to zero at 16:50. The error counter per day is reset at 15:50 on the next day.